# Вставить плейлист YouTube на сайт

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, youtube-api

Вот HTML

```
<div id="video" ></div>
```

Вот JS

```
$('#video').YTPlayer({
    playerVars: {
        listType:'playlist',
        list: 'PLl9Dbw92gld_q8il6fzIGUbc2bdFu8w-8',
        modestbranding: 0,
        wmode: 'transparent',
        rel: 0,
        origin: location.origin
    }
});
```

Консоль выдает ошибку

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).YTPlayer is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (scripts.js:198)
    at e (jquery-3.4.0.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery-3.4.0.min.js:2)
```

Как правильно вставить плейлист с YouTube?

Comment: А почему вы решили, что некий YTPlayer должен существовать?

Comment: У заказчика на сайте http://sender.services/ru/ есть такой скрипт. Увидел через инспектор. Если чужой код не работает у меня то можно написать свой код.

Comment: Может, это пригодится: https://habr.com/post/306726/

Comment: отправил вопрос на этот пост https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/971044/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82-%D1%81-youtube-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82

Answer (score 0):

А чем вас не устраивает обычная вставка через 
Как поделиться обычным видео и выбрать код, только нужно после части embed/ добавить videoseries?list=ID
где ID - это идентификатор плей листа, его можно скопировать из поисковой стройки ютуба, когда вы открываете плейслист.

Итого для ставки через  код будет выглядеть примерно так

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLQ0imTFUuNUnNA2crs55Pfmlk1V6LUq3i" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```